# Turn a windows application to dark mode without supporting it?

Tags: windows-10, dark-mode

I'm trying to use an application "**WINAUTOMATION**" in **Windows 10** in **dark mode**, I know that is possible in **Settings**, but only for apps that support it. I'm wondering why this is possible in Android 10 to force app to be darker even if it doesn't support it. I did a little research on google, but no answers.

Is there any method on **Windows 10** to use programs that doesn't support Dark mode, I really want to use my pc overnight but can't use this applications :( (even with night mode, the app have an intense white color in background).

Thanks a lot .

Comment: If the app does not support dark mode, try very warm Windows 10 night mode.

Comment: Android and Windows are entirely two different operating systems.  What is possible in Android often is not possible in any other operating system.

Comment: Yeah, the application have an intense white color in background, so even if I have night mode on, it hurts my eyes :(

Comment: Does [this method](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/133985-change-window-background-color-windows-10-a.html)? (It pertains to most apps.)

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work, well the app I'm using is **Winautomation**, I think it's impossible to change to dark mode ? Maybe, the app uses it's own theme or somethinglike that.